# Could not infer template argument when using "typename Container::value_type" as the return value

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

First define a generic function whose purpose is to execute a function for a list of inputs, and print out each input and the corresponding function execution result.

In the following, `func` is a reference to a function, `funcName` is just the function name for terminal display, `inputs` are arguments for `func`.

```
#define TBOLD(x) "\x1B[1m" x __RST
#define TRED(x) __KRED x __RST

template<typename ...TInputs, typename TOutput>
void test_func(TOutput func(TInputs &...), 
        const string &funcName, 
        vector<tuple<TInputs...>> inputs,
        const string &resultDelimiter = ", ")
{
    cout << funcName << endl;
    if (is_same<TOutput, bool>::value)
        cout << boolalpha;

    for (auto &input: inputs)
    {
        auto arg_idx = 0;
        apply([&arg_idx](auto &&... args)
              { ((std::cout << args << (++arg_idx == sizeof...(TInputs) ? TBOLD(TRED(" : ")) : ", ")), ...); }, input);
        cout << apply(func, input) << endl;
    }
}
```

Now suppose I have the following functions,

```
static int func1(vector<int> &arr, int &k)
{
    sort(arr.begin(),arr.end());
    return arr[k];
}

template<typename Container>
static typename Container::value_type func2(Container &arr, int &k)
{
    sort(arr.begin(),arr.end());
    return arr[k];
}
```

Now the following line will compile,

```
test_func(func1,"func1",vector<tuple<vector<int>,int>>{make_tuple(vector<int>{3,5,1,2,4},2)})
```

but the following **won't compile** and gives a message that "**could not infer template argument TOutput**". In my opinion, this should have provided enough information to infer the output type `TOutput`: the `inputs` argument is of type `vector<tuple<vector<int>,int>>`, then it should know `TInputs...` is `<Container, int>`, and then `TOutput` is `Container::value_type`.

```
test_func(func2,"func2",vector<tuple<vector<int>,int>>{make_tuple(vector<int>{3,5,1,2,4},2)})
```

If this is indeed not working, **what is the right way to make the return type correctly recognized, while preserving the "generality"** of this `test_func` to accept functions of different arguments and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way template parameter deduction works, template parameters are deduced separately from each argument. After that, every parameter must be determined at least once, and if it's determined more than once, all deductions must produce the same type.

You seem to expect `TInputs` to be deduced from `inputs` argument, then plugged into `func` argument in the hopes that `TOutput` will come out. Template parameter deduction doesn't work this way.